How to reference a button created in a foreach loop
How to reference a button created in a for each loop
I have the following code where I apply a custom buttonStyle to a set of buttons created using a ForEach loop. I’m trying to make it so that two things happen: When a button is pressed 1. If it is the correct button, (i.e. matches the userprompt) its border flashes green before generating a new userprompt (This I’ve managed to achieve for the most part), 2. If it is the wrong button, then the button that matches the userprompt flashes Red to indicate to the user which button should have been pressed.
I’ve tried two different ways of creating this effect. Firstly using a function that triggers when the button is pressed, passing in the buttons border colour, but this didn’t work as it didn’t allow me to specify which button should flash red in the case of a wrong press.
Now I’ve been trying to do it via custom buttonStyle, but this is similar in practice except it does a lot more of what I want.
TLDR ; Essentially, I’m having trouble referencing a single instance from a group of buttons that were created by a forEach loop. I’m imagining I need to include a second conditional inside my checking conditional that says something like “If button matches the userprompt, then flash just that button red”. But unsure how to do that.
Here is what I have so far:
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    var fullArray = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
    var topArray = ["1","2","3"]
    var botArray = ["4","5","6"]
    @State private var userPrompt = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
    @State private var newLetter = ""
    @State private var borderColor = Color.black
    @State private var letterTapped = ""
    func chosenLetter() -> String {
        return userPrompt.randomElement() ?? "Not working"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(newLetter)
                .padding()
                .font(.title)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            HStack {
                
                ForEach(topArray, id: \.self) { topLetter in
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Top number keys")
                    }){
                        Text(topLetter)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(keyLabel: topLetter, newLetter: $newLetter, borderColor: $borderColor))

                }
                
            }
            HStack{
                ForEach(botArray, id: \.self){ botLetter in
                    Button(action:{
                        print("Bottom number keys")
                    }){
                        Text(botLetter)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(keyLabel: botLetter, newLetter: $newLetter, borderColor:  $borderColor))
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
          newLetter = chosenLetter()
        }
    }
    struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
        let keyLabel: String
        @State var isPressed = false
        @Binding var newLetter : String 
        @Binding public var borderColor: Color
//        @Binding var correctLetter : Bool
        
        func chooseBorder() -> Color {
            if keyLabel == newLetter {
                if isPressed{
                    return Color.green
                }
            }else{
                return Color.black
            }
            return Color.black
        }
        
        func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
            configuration.label
                .padding()
                .border(chooseBorder())

                .onTapGesture {
                    isPressed = true
                    // Change border color if label matches userPrompt
                    if keyLabel == newLetter {
                        borderColor = .green
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4)
                        {
                            borderColor = Color.black
                        }

                    }else{
                        borderColor = .red
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4)
                            {
                                borderColor = Color.black
                            }    
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}


I have tried completing this as a function that runs in the buttons action instead of through a custom button style.
One idea I’ve had is that I could generate a dictionary that has each string and an associated value. This might then allow me to reference that button based on its value. But I think I might be over complicating it

It's ForEach(1..<4) { x in for a constant range. If dynamic you must pass a valid unique identifier keypath can't use self.

borderColor should not be a @State in ContentView. Each button has its own border color. In fact, each button doesn't need a borderColor as its state either. The border color of the button is determined by chooseBorder, which depends on keyLetter, newLetter and isPressed. chooseBorder should be implemented like this:
func chooseBorder() -> Color {
    if keyLabel == newLetter && isPressed {
        return Color.green
    } else if isPressed {
        return Color.red
    }
    return Color.black
}

Instead of setting borderColor after 0.4 seconds, set isPressed to false.
.onTapGesture {
    isPressed = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4)
    {
        isPressed = false
    }
    if keyLabel == newLetter {
        newLetter = // choose a new letter...
    }
}

I do think you are over-complicating this though. You can just create a custom button View instead:
struct CustomButton: View {
    let keyLabel: String
    let newLetter: String
    let action: () -> Void
    @State var borderColor = Color.black
    @State var flashTrigger = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(keyLabel)
            .padding()
            .border(borderColor)
            .onTapGesture {
                flashTrigger.toggle()
            }
            .task(id: flashTrigger) {
                borderColor = keyLabel == newLetter ? .green : .red
                do {
                    try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(400))
                } catch {
                    return
                }
                borderColor = .black
                if keyLabel == newLetter {
                    action()
                }
            }
    }
}

Usage:
HStack {
    ForEach(topArray, id: \.self) { topLetter in
        CustomButton(keyLabel: topLetter, newLetter: newLetter) {
            newLetter = chosenLetter()
        }
    }
}
HStack{
    ForEach(botArray, id: \.self){ botLetter in
        CustomButton(keyLabel: botLetter, newLetter: newLetter) {
            newLetter = chosenLetter()
        }
    }
}


Thank you. I’ll give this a go tonight and see how I land. I thought I might be going the wrong way about it
